# Gender considerations in web usage

Tags: website-design, research, gender

Are there particular gender differences in web usage/preferences? I'm about to start designing an information-based site with a predominantly female audience. I was wondering what research already exists that might provide any useful insights? Most research tends to focus on gender behaviour differences on e-commerce or social networking sites, but I haven't found much in terms of information sites.

I'm aware of [ComScore's article "Women on the Web How Women are Shaping the Internet"](http://www.comscore.com/Press_Events/Presentations_Whitepapers/2010/Women_on_the_Web_How_Women_are_Shaping_the_Internet)
and [the gender section on Experientia](http://www.experientia.com/blog/category/gender/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit: 11 December 2010**

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/are-male-and-female-designers-designed-differently.html

---

These 2 articles are good read

> According to some recent research by
>   the University of Glamorgan, if you
>   are designing a site primarily aimed
>   at women, it is worth ensuring a
>   female designer is working on it.
>
> Source:
>   http://boagworld.com/design/sugar-and-spice

Usability Study: Men Need Speed

Source http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/usability-criteria/

And this PDF also

[Gender Preferences in Web Design: Usability Testing through Eye ...](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.4123&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

---

**30 June 2012** - I came across to one more good article today

http://www.netmagazine.com/features/designing-experiences-women

Comment: @Tom Evans - Your Welcome Tom :)

Answer (score 2):

Gender Differences in Website Production and Aesthetic Preferences: http://www.iiisci.org/journal/CV$/sci/pdfs/I196XFB.pdf

Gender and Web Design: http://www.acrwebsite.org/volumes/gmcb_v08/CP%20paper%2030%20Gloria%20Moss.pdf

Also, try ERIC (not Google) for more papers - although you may have to pay for access to some of them (do ERIC first then Google a paper's name if it's not available direct from ERIC - many are hosted for free on sites that ERIC doesn't link to).

Comment: Sometimes I have to wonder about academics. The Moss-Gunn study concludes that, yes, there are gender differences that warrant design differences, and the Moss-Gunn-Kubacki study says to use design elements that your intended audience likes. LOL! Thanks for posting these links. :)

Answer (score 0):

@TomEvans: I don't know if you're aware of http://scholar.google.com/schhp?hl=en&tab=ws or not, but it might help you in your search for academic material.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that - thanks Andrew